# Erlang: how to get multiple releases running at the same time?

Tags: erlang, rebar

Is it possible to have multiple releases created by rebar to run at the same time? I have one server where I'd like to run different releases simultaneously to test them out. The problem is when I do:

`rel/myapp_a/bin/myapp_a stop`

It manages to stop my VM which is running `myapp_b`

How do I get them to run as their own entities that do not interfere with each other?

Comment: Are the erang vm's running as connected nodes?

Comment: They shouldn't be. I just want to run them as individual nodes for testing purposes. Same app, just different versions of it.

Comment: Are the two nodes running with the same cookie maybe and being connected to each other?

Comment: That's also possible. I need to figure out how to set unique cookie names in a rebar release.

Comment: I don't think cookies should be in the release itself.

Comment: Actually I changed the nodename and cookie names to be unique in rel/files/vm.args and that didn't do it either. it thinks the node is already running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I would check if the two nodes are connected to each other:

On one or each of the nodes run

```
Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)
1> nodes().
[]
```

and make sure the list is empty or only containing other nodes that are supposed to be connected.

Check if the nodes can be connected at all by calling [netadm:ping/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_adm.html) and try to connect the nodes.  If they can be connected and shouldn't make sure to run them with different cookies.